# Fromcraft Plugin On click submit button

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

When i click on submit button of form which made by FromCraft Plugin in wordpress.I purchased it still it does not work properly.
The link like
[http://techhive.co.in/translatpedia/form-view/2] works fine.

But when i embed php code in page

```
<?php 
                            if (function_exists("add_formcraft_form"))
                            { add_formcraft_form("[fc id='2'][/fc]"); } 
                            ?>
```

It doesn't work.it shows on click submit button like this

[http://techhive.co.in/translatpedia/contact-us/?field1=&field2%5B%5D=&field3%5B%5D=&field5%5B%5D=&field6%5B%5D=Language+combinations&field7%5B%5D=&field11%5B%5D=&field10%5B%5D=&field14%5B%5D=&field9%5B%5D=&field13%5B%5D=&field8%5B%5D=&field12%5B%5D=&field16%5B%5D=&field17%5B%5D=&field18%5B%5D=&field19%5B%5D=&field20=&field23%5B%5D=&field24%5B%5D=&field25=&files=&website=](http://techhive.co.in/translatpedia/contact-us/?field1=&field2%5B%5D=&field3%5B%5D=&field5%5B%5D=&field6%5B%5D=Language%20combinations&field7%5B%5D=&field11%5B%5D=&field10%5B%5D=&field14%5B%5D=&field9%5B%5D=&field13%5B%5D=&field8%5B%5D=&field12%5B%5D=&field16%5B%5D=&field17%5B%5D=&field18%5B%5D=&field19%5B%5D=&field20=&field23%5B%5D=&field24%5B%5D=&field25=&files=&website=)

What is the problem with this?
Is there any integration required?Please help me out for this.

Comment: As per the site rules we can't provide assistance on third party plugin! This is something you should ask on plugin's support page.